# Is \n multi-character in C?

Tags: c, cross-platform, ascii, newline, eol

I read that \n consists of CR & LF. Each has their own ASCII codes.

So is the \n in C represented by a single character or is it multi-character?

**Edit:** Kindly specify your answer, rather than simply saying *"yes, it is"* or *"no, it isn't"*

Comment: \n is LF or 0x0A in ASCII \r is CR 0x0D in ASCII

Comment: "\n consists of CR & LF"?  Really?  Where did you read this?  Can you provide a link or a quote?  It's an odd thing to claim.

Comment: @S.Lott, I think it stems from some windows applications that use both \n\r to define a newline

Comment: @S.Lott: There are some applications/libraries that do the conversion automatically, so that might be it.

Comment: "\n\r" used in Windows is quite different from the claim that "\n" is two characters.  I'd like to see a quote or a link for the actual claim in the question, since it's so strange.

Comment: Either way, it's "\r\n", not "\n\r" - CR LF, not LF CR.

Comment: Wikipedia has an excellent discussion on the history behind CRLF bs LF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally: `'\n'` is a single character, which represents a newline. `'\r'` is a single character, which represents a carriage-return. They are their own independent ASCII characters.

Issues arise because in the actual file representation, UNIX-based systems tend to use `'\n'` alone to represent what you think of when you hit "enter" or "return" on the keyboard, whereas Windows uses a `'\r'` followed directly by a `'\n'`.

In a file:

```
"This is my UNIX file\nwhich spans two lines"
"This is my Windows file\r\nwhich spans two lines"
```

Of course, like all binary data, these characters are all about interpretation, and that interpretation depends on the application using the data. [Stick to '\n' when you are making C-strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages), unless you want a literal carriage-return, because as people have pointed out in the comments, the OS representation doesn't concern you. IO libraries, including C's, are supposed to handle this themselves and abstract it away from you.

For your curiosity, in decimal, `'\n'` in ASCII is 10, `'\r'` is 13, but note that this is the ASCII standard, not a C standard.

Comment: @Andre:  Then Apple went with an entirely new Unix-based system (now a real Unix) for their OS.

Comment: This answer seems kind of confusing without providing context.  It matters where/how `\n` is used; `\n` is converted to the necessary newline sequence (e.g. `\r\n` on Windows) automatically for text-mode streams.

Comment: When '\n' is written to a file it is converted to the platform specific EOL sequence (If the file is in text mode). When the file is read back into memory the EOL sequence is converted into the character '\n'. The problem occures when a file is saved on one plattform and used on another that has a different EOL sequence. Internally in memory the EOL is always '\n'. So technically your string example is not 100% accurate as you should mention that these are the file formats used by the two systems.

Comment: **\n** is not necessarily an ASCII 10.  The C standard does not specify which character is used to specify **\n** internally.

Comment: @JeremyP: Agreed, but my statement is still accurate. '\n' is always 10 in ASCII. However I have updated the statement to be less ambiguous. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

In a C program, it's a single character, `'\n'`representing end of line.  However, some operating systems (most notably Microsoft Windows) use two characters to represent end of line in text files, and this is likely where the confusion comes from.

It's the responsibility of the C I/O functions to do the conversions between the C representation of `'\n'` and whatever the OS uses.

In C programs, simply use `'\n'`.  It is guaranteed to be correct.  When looking at text files with some sort of editor, you might see two characters.    When a text file is transferred from Windows to some Unix-based system, you might get `"^M"` showing up at the end of each line, which is annoying, but has nothing to do with C.

Comment: +1 the correct answer. Note: Every OS has its own specific EOL sequence. It is the responsability of the C I/O runtime to convert between '\n' and the EOL sequence of the current platform. Note: Old Mac used '\r' as the EOL sequence. But in the code it is always '\n'

Comment: +1. This is really confusing yes. Wish every OS used Unix endings, sigh. But no, let's all use different characters.

Comment: @Skumedel - Which operating systems released in the last 5 years (besides windows) use something other than `\n`? It's not *that* confusing :)

Comment: @Skumedel - Actually, if you think about it almost everything EXCEPT for *nix and Mac OS classic uses \r\n. Look at raw HTTP (or for that matter almost any text based protocol) headers for an example.

Comment: Yeah, we really need to put an end to this confusion ;)

Comment: @Novikov @Seth: It's confusing enough when you deal with both endings. My point was having different endings in the first place in use by two different OS' is confusing. And protocols are not really related in my opinion, a protocol usually have well defined terminations because an ambigious protocol is hardly desirable. Ambiguous line endings is also not desirable, but it's what we have.

Comment: @MSalters: No, it's not like I'm killing myself over it, but I think it's one of those things that bite you in the arse from time to time for no good reason. Feel free to ridicule me further, but I'd take a well-defined behaviour over anything else.

Comment: @Skurmedel : it was a bad pun, did you miss the smiley ?

Comment: @MSalters: No, I missed the pun and took the smiley as sarcasm. :( Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

It depends:

- `'\n'` is a single character (ASCII LF)
- `"\n"` is a `'\n'` character followed by a 0 terminator

some I/O operations transform a `'\n'` into `'\r\n'` on some systems (CR-LF).

Comment: ALL text-based I/O operations transform a '\n' into '\r\n' on SOME systems.

Answer (score 4):

When you print the `\n` to a file, using the windows C stdio libraries, the library interprets that as a logical new-line, not the literal character `0x0A`. The output to the file will be the windows version of a new-line: `0x0D0A` (`\r\n`).

**Writing**

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("foo.txt","w");
    fprintf(f,"foo\nbar");
    return 0;
}
```

A quick `cl /EHsc foo.c` later and you get

```
0x666F6F 0x0D0A 0x626172 (separated for convenience)
```

in foo.txt under a hex editor.

It's important to note that this translation DOES NOT occur if you are writing to a file in 'binary mode'.

**Reading**

If you are reading the file back in using the same tools, also on windows, the "windows EOL" will be interpreted properly if you try to match up against `\n`.

When reading it back

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("foo.txt", "r");
    char c;
    while (EOF != fscanf(f, "%c", &c))
        printf("%x-", c);
}
```

You get

```
 66-6f-6f-a-62-61-72-
```

Therefore, the only time this should be relevant to you is if you are

- Moving files back and forth between mac/unix and windows.  Unix needs no real explanation here, since `\n` directly translates to `0x0A` on those platforms. (pre-OSX `\n` was `0x0D` on mac iirc)
- Putting text in binary files, only do this carefully please
- Trying to figure out why your binary data is being messed up when you opened the file "w", instead of "wb"
- Estimating something important based on the size of the file, on windows you'll have an extra byte per newline.

Answer (score 3):

`\n` is a new-line -- it's a *logical* representation of whatever separates one line from another in a text file.

A given platform will have some physical representation of that logical separation between lines. On Unix and most similar systems, the new-line is represented by a line-feed (LF) character (and since Unix was/is so closely associated with C, on Unix the LF is often just called a new-line). On MacOS, it's typically represented by a carriage-return (CR). On a fair number of other systems, most prominently Windows, it's represented by a carriage return/line feed pair -- normally in that order, though once in a while you see something use LF followed by CR (as I recall, Clarion used to do that).

In theory, a new-line doesn't need to correspond to any characters in the stream at all though. For example, a system could have text files that were stored as a length followed by the appropriate number of characters. In such a case, the run-time library would need to carry out a slightly more extensive translation between internal and external representations of text files than is now common, but such is life.

Comment: I don't think it is a logical representation, you know. In C on an ASCII system, ('\n' == 10) is guaranteed to be true. There might be conversions from newline to local line ending when doing IO, but the meaning of \n per se is always a newline.

Comment: @Tom: You're not guaranteed anything of the sort. You're guaranteed that when represented as a `char`, that '\n' will have a positive value -- nothing more. Most implementations *do* use the value 10, but they could perfectly legitimately use another value.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C99 Standard (section 5.2.2),

> **\n** "moves the active position [where the next character from fputc would appear] to the initial position on the next line".

Also

> [**\n**] shall produce a unique implementation-defined value
>   which can be stored in a single char object. The external representations in a text file
>   need not be identical to the internal representations and are outside the scope of [the C99 Standard]

Most C implementations choose to define `\n` as ASCII line feed (0x0A) for historical reasons.  However, on many computer operating systems, the sequence for moving the active position to the beginning of the next line requires two characters usually 0x0D, 0x0A.  So, when writing to a text file, the C implementation must convert the internal sequence of 0x0A to the external one of 0x0D, 0x0A. How this is done is outside of the scope of the C standard, but usually, the file IO library will perform the conversion on any file opened in text mode.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about text files.

A *text file* is a sequence of lines.
A *line* is a sequence of characters ending in (and including) a line break.
A *line breaks* is represented differently by different Operating Systems.

On Unix/Linux/Mac they are usually represented by a single LINEFEED
On Windows they are usually represented by the pair CARRIAGE RETURN + LINEFEED
On old Macs they were usually represented by a single CARRIAGE RETURN
On other systems (AS/400 ??) there may even not be a specific character that represents a line break ...

Anyway, the library code in `C` is responsible to translating the system's line break to `'\n'` when reading **text files** and do the reverse operation when writing **text files**.

So, no matter what the representation is on any given system, when you read a **text file** in `C`, lines will be ended by a `'\n'`.

*Note: The `'\n'` is not necessarily `0x0a` in all systems.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

`\n` is a newline. Hex code is 0x0A.

`\r` is a carriage return. Hex code is 0x0D

Answer (score 0):

It is a single character.  It represents Newline (but is not the only representation - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)).

EDIT: The question was changed while I was typing the answer.