# Are newline characters counted twice?

Tags: c, count, character, newline

I have written a C program to count the `words`,`characters` and `lines` in a text file. The program is reading lines and words correctly but is not counting the total characters correctly.

I am using GitBash on windows, so I used the `wc` command for checking my program's correctness. It always shows **x** characters more than that my program's output, where **x** is the no. of new line characters in my program.

Here is my program:

```
#define IN 1 // if getc is reading the word
#define OUT 0 // if getc has read the word and now reading the spaces

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("lorum ipsum.txt","r");
    int lineCount = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int charCount = 0;
    int c;
    int position = IN; //tells about the reading position of getc whether reading the word or has read the word

    while((c=getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            lineCount++;
        }
        if(c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c==' ')
        {
            if(position == IN) // means just finished reading the word
            {
                wordCount++;
                position = OUT; // is now reading the white spaces  
            }
        }
        else if(position == OUT)
        {
            //puts("This position is reached");
            position = IN; //currently reading the word
        }

        charCount++;
    }

    // printing to output
    return 0;
}
```

Here the whole code does not matter, what matter is that I am increasing the `charCount` variable for every character read by `getc` in the `while` loop.

Also, I checked for the `'\n'` character size by using `sizeof()`, it is just a simple character and occupies 1 byte; so we should count it as one.

Also from the **file size** I came to know that `wc` is outputting the correct results. So what is the problem, is there any issue in the encoding in which my text file is stored?

**NOTE:** Every time I add a newline in my text file by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the size of the file is increased by **two** and so as the number of characters counted by the `wc` command but my program's output characters change by **one**.

**EDIT:** According to the good answers I understood that there are extra `\r` characters at the newline. So when `r` mode is used it interprets the newlines as `\n`, only when using the binary mode `rb` it shows up the actual `\r\n`. Here is the answer about this behavior:
[what's the differences between r and rb in fopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174889/whats-the-differences-between-r-and-rb-in-fopen)

Comment: Try `fopen("lorum ipsum.txt","rb");`. By default windows line endings: `\r\n` are converted to unix: `\n`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, fixed the typo, still not working.

Comment: Please show your printing to the output.

Comment: "i checked for the '\n' character size" -- smart, but not smart enough. Newline type differences lie not in the *size* of this character but in its interpretation inside library functions.

Comment: @Jongware, all newlines character will be treated as the newlines formatter as per the ASCII standards;i.e i guess you are saying about  interpretation inside library functions

Comment: @Banthar, so i tried your solution. It worked but why  r or rt modes are not working.

Comment: If you want to count `\r` characters, you need `"rb"` mode under Windows because otherwise they are filtered out in your program. Of course, that does not happen in showing the total file size in a DIR listing.

Comment: if `wc` is counting each newline twice then don't use it

Comment: @Jongware, quite helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows new line consists of two characters. One is `\r` as carriage return and another is `\n` as line feed. By checking only for `\n`, you missed `\r` char.

See [What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n) for more details.

Comment: What a newline consists of is definitly OS dependend.

Comment: This is not the case if the file is opened in text mode.

Comment: OK!! that's helpful but what should i do read the file in proper format, "r" mode is not reading in correct format.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to [end a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation). Currently macOS and Linux use just one byte but Windows uses the pair CR-LF because it has been used since CP/M and then carried over to DOS. See

- [Why does Windows use CR LF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6521685/995714)
- [Difference between '\n' and '\r\n'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/29075/98103)
- [Why is Windows using CRLF and Unix just LF when Unix is the older system?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6381/1981)
- [Why is the line terminator CR+LF?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=40193)

When you open a file in text mode, the C runtime library will automatically convert the system line ending character(s) (`'\r\n'` in this case) to `'\n'` and count only once. For example on class Mac where the new line character is `'\r'` then reading it in text mode will produce `'\n'`. When printing using `printf` and some other functions the reverse thing will happen: `'\n'` will be converted to the system's newline character.

In practice you should generally open the file in text mode except when you want to deal with the line ending yourself (like when you need to open files in various line ending formats on a single platform). That will count the **number of lines** correctly. But to count the **number of bytes** you need to open in binary mode. But why take such a hassle when you can simply get the file size directly without any counting?

See also

- [Difference between files written in binary and text mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229924/995714)
- [Is \n multi-character in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3671462/995714)
- [Does Windows carriage return \r\n consist of two characters or one character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7013034/995714)
- [Carriage return required when printing to the console in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728312/995714)
- [What is the value of '\n' under C compilers for old Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25065940/995714)

Comment: Good, but (1) the OP wants to count both words *and* total number of characters, so `\r` needs to be read; (2) the text file may not originate from a Windows system, so *always* counting a single `\n` as 2 characters is "over-correcting".

Comment: @Jongware I didn't say that always counting a single `\n` as 2 characters, I mean the `'\r\n'` pair. He wants to count the number of characters, not bytes, so he must count the pair as one

Comment: But that is only valid if you are *sure* there are `\r` characters in the input. No way to know *unless* you use `"rb"` (and then you can still count just the `\n` as a single new line, and only add 1 for each `\r` in the "total" character count).